# Puma .NET exception 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'

Tags: c#, .net, ocr

Trying to recognise a set of images in a folder (using Puma .NET OCR library), the first image is recognised successfully, but after that I get an error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' 
occurred in Puma.Net.dll

Additional information: <0x00000000>: ?????? ???.
```

I have a special class for recognition, and the error happens on this line:

```
Puma.Net.PumaPage inputFile = new Puma.Net.PumaPage(imagePath);
```

I found [this link](https://pumanet.codeplex.com/discussions/221779) and [this one](https://pumanet.codeplex.com/discussions/198669), but they don't seem to help in my case.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by using 'using' statement

```
 using(Puma.Net.PumaPage inputFile = new Puma.Net.PumaPage(imagePath))
        {
        }
```

Comment: I tried this on my machine but no luck. I am getting  error

An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in Puma.Net.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: <0xFFFFFFFF>: Library PUMA.DLL not load.

Comment: try removing the library then re-include it (works with NuGet PM)

Comment: 1. Check that the environment path  variable contains this path : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Puma.NET\COM Server"
2. Grant the executing user to read/write the Com server as well.